# blocked by play protect on huawei AppGallery

Tags: mobile, expo, huawei-developers, appgallery

I wanted to publish the application that I published on google play to huawei appGallery. I used the same .aab file. I extracted this aab file with expo react native and expo managed the signature. I then shared the signed app on appGallery. It said I had to install a certificate with the .pem extension so I could install it. I created a new keystore jks and pem file. I have added this pem file to appGallery. Then my app was published.

Only users get a "blocked by play protect" warning when they try to download the application. If they accept this, the application will download. But it does not leave a good impression for users. Why do you think this happens?

Answer (score 1):

"I created a new keystore jks and pem file"

----Do not use the new keystore file. Use the same keystore file as google play.

[image]

Select the second method to upload the data to the Huawei platform.
For more info, kindly check docs:https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/AppGallery-connect-Guides/agc-appsigning-newapp-0000001052418290#section146431407275

Comment: I managed to sign with expo. I will check if the certificate is exported. I have a question. I published the app on huawei appGallery with another package name. How does Google know it's the same app?  Or do I need to upload it to google play first to publish an app in appGallery?

Comment: This is a Google Protect tip and should be identified via a signature by google. The signature of the app does not exist in the Google database. Therefore, the app is considered insecure. If you have an app's signature that has been posted on Google, Google should not report an error.  @Ali Bulut

Comment: Does your package contain gms or google play code? If there is no such code, no error message should be displayed. And no error "blocked by play protect" should be displayed when you put it online in the Huawei AppGallery.

Comment: I will try method 1. I will create a pem file with the keystore I use in google play and send it to appGallery. I will post the result again

For option 2, I'm not sure if gsm is used in the project. I just changed the package name and got the android build with expo. I sent a new password. I was already getting an error in this scenario

Comment: Thanks queen, I did as you said. Tried on 2 different accounts. 1 of them happened directly. For some reason it didn't work in the 2nd, so I updated the sdk in the application and did the same thing again. I tested it a week later and it was successful too.

Answer (score 0):

This warning may have been received if the application was downloaded from AppGallery on a device with GMS. Did you download the apk file you uploaded to AppGallery from Play Store? Because Google Play Store signs it. If you did this, please generate an apk from your own jks file and then upload that apk to AppGallery. This issue can be caused by signature mismatch.